# Identify OneDrive shortcuts in a folder from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, onedrive

A recent upgrade to Microsoft 365/OneDrive allows users to add a shortcut to a document library into the root of their personal OneDrive folder:

[image: Add shortcut to OneDrive]

It looks like this in File Explorer:

[image: OneDrive shortcuts in File Explorer]

How do you identify these folders in PowerShell? `Get-ChildItem` returns identical fields for this shortcut as for the "Documents" folder, specifically `Mode` and `Attributes` fields are identical so can't be used to distinguish.

The problem I've got is that we have a script that backs up the user's OneDrive folder (as OneDrive is horrible when you restore a VM snapshot) but it's now dragging in the entire contents of the target folders. The script uses robocopy and `/xj` doesn't work. I need to identify these shortcuts so I can pass them to robocopy via `/xd`.

Comment: What is the value of `Attributes` for the link? `525329`? If you view the contents of the directory in **Cmd** / **PowerShell** (using -Force), does it contain a `desktop.ini` file and a `target.lnk` file?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pain, since OneDrive uses its own type of NTFS `ReparsePoint`, so even the new versions of powershell don't have the tools to view the target, or really differentiate one from another. I did find they have a specific reparse point tag by using `Get-ReparsePoint` from the powershell community extensions module (pscx). In this case, `Documents\` is a link to a sharepoint document library, and `TestFolder\` is a folder created in windows explorer:

```
Get-ChildItem -Attributes ReparsePoint | Get-ReparsePoint

Path                                                            ReparsePointTag
----                                                            ---------------
C:\users\user\OneDrive - domain.com\Documents                   2415943706
C:\users\user\OneDrive - domain.com\Microsoft Teams Chat Files  2415943706
C:\users\user\OneDrive - domain.com\Notebooks                   2415943706
C:\users\user\OneDrive - domain.com\TestFolder                  2415976474
C:\users\user\OneDrive - domain.com\TestFolder\test.txt         2415943706
C:\users\user\OneDrive - domain.com\Test.txt                    2415943706
```

I converted the tag values to hex, and used [this Microsoft Docs list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/c8e77b37-3909-4fe6-a4ea-2b9d423b1ee4) of reparse point tags to see... not much, just that these are all OneDrive-related:

```
2415935514 = 0x9000401A = IO_REPARSE_TAG_CLOUD_4
2415943706 = 0x9000601A = IO_REPARSE_TAG_CLOUD_6
2415976474 = 0x9000E01A = IO_REPARSE_TAG_CLOUD_E
```

From the small amount of testing I did, I think you could use this to list directories with the `ReparsePointTag` of `2415943706` and feed them to your robocopy script to exclude them.

It might be a better idea to revisit using robocopy to back up a user's local onedrive files instead of something native to onedrive.

Comment: Thanks for this: Get-ReparsePoint looks like a way to at least identify these shortcuts. One assumes that the PowerShell cmdlets will be updated at some point to allow Get-ChildItem to identify them maybe via attributes/mode

Comment: Sadly, after returning to this many months later, all of the reparse points have the value 2415943706. The one that's a shortcut to another document library has the same tag :-(

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this :-(

Answer (score 1):

I found a different way to do this, based on OneDrive setting the icon type for these shortcuts to a specific "link" icon:

[image: screenshot]

You can check each folder for a `desktop.ini` hidden system file that specifies `IconResource=*OneDrive.exe,4` like this:

```
# get a list of folders in onedrive
$OneDriveDirs = Get-ChildItem $env:OneDrive -Recurse -Directory

# check each folder for the onedrive link icon
$OneDriveLinks = foreach ($folder in $OneDriveDirs) {
  if (Test-Path $folder\desktop.ini) {
    if ((Get-Content $folder\desktop.ini -Force) -match 'IconResource=.*OneDrive.exe,4') {
      $folder
    }
  }
}
$OneDriveLinks.FullName

# outputs
C:\Users\user\OneDrive - domain.com\Documents
C:\Users\user\OneDrive - domain.com\General
```

---

I checked the other onedrive icons and saw a second folder link icon at index **7**, so maybe check for both?

[image: icons]

I'll also recommend using an actual backup service like veeam instead of backing up the locally-synced items. For example, what happens if the user wasn't logged into onedrive for a while?

Comment: Excellent bit of thinking outside of the box! Thanks - will look at implementing it... Because OneDrive is *so* flaky, in development I'm always backing up my OneDrive to network storage. However, the script has started copying all the projects and more importantly, I don't want them copied back!

Comment: Although to be honest, OneDrive has got a bit better in this area. It used to have a very nasty habit of dragging back long deleted folders & files if you happened to restore a very old image/snapshot. They seemed to have fixed that critical flaw.

Comment: On Windows 11, the icon index was 7

Comment: I've added this into my robocopy based backup script and it works a treat. A little sketchy but it'll have to do until Microsoft implement some API/function to detect the shortcut folder